# Managing with oscillation and torsion in newton Raphson method without limiting iterations

Tags: matlab, newtons-method

I've been trying to write a MATLAB-function which calculates the a root of a function simply by using Newton-Raphson. The problem with this algorithm is it diverges near torsion points and roots with oscillations (e.g for x^2+2 after 10 iteration with initial guess -1 the method diverges). Is there any satisfying condition to identify when we get oscillations and torsions which doesn't count iterations in a really inefficient way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You  may be interested in the Matlab File Exchange entry called ["Newton Raphson Solver with adaptive Step Size"](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/matlabcentral/fileexchange/40038-newton-raphson-solver-with-adaptive-step-size). It implements the Newton-Raphson method to extract the roots of a polynomial.

In particular, this function has a `while` staement on line 147. Simply replace

```
while( err > ConvCrit && n < maxIter)
```

with

```
while( err > ConvCrit) %removing the maximum iteration criterion
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd argue that your initial estimate of `-1` is poor, hence the estimation error is large and this is what probably causes the algorithm to overshoot and oscillate (and eventually diverge).

You could consider doing [*successive over-relaxation*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Successive_over-relaxation) by multiplying the quotient `f(xn)/f'(xn)` by a positive factor. I recommended you to look up methods for *adaptive* successive over-relaxation (which I won't elaborate here), that (adaptively) set the relaxation parameter iteratively based on the observed behavior of the converging process.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you are trying to solve a function which does not have any real roots... so the newton raphson is not going to provide you any results for any initial guess..